Yii2 Docker Mysql can connect to heidi sql
I've installed the yii2 advance application and run the default docker-compose.yml file
docker compose build

after that i run
docker compose up

and, in my docker desktop i can see everything is ok.

Then i modify my common/config/main-local.php to connect db
'db' => [
          'class' => \yii\db\Connection::class,
          'dsn' => 'mysql:host=mysql;dbname=yiicms',
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => 'verysecret',
          'charset' => 'utf8',
],

And this give me the error :

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'yiicms'

Error Info: Array
(
[0] => HY000
1 => 1049
2 => Unknown database 'yiicms'
)
I'll try to create the db with heidisql but i don't know how to connect it, when i try to connect to 127.0.0.1 with username and password gives me cannot connect error

This is the docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.2'

services:

  frontend:
    build: frontend
    ports:
      - 20080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  backend:
    build: backend
    ports:
      - 21080:80
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_USER=yii2advanced
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret


Why do you need to create new database? When you are using docker the DB for app is already created as yii2advanced when mysql container is set up. Are you maybe following the general installation guide instead of Installing using Docker section?

Yeah I see it crete the db but, for example, i clone an existing project so i need to import a db dump into the db... this is why i thought to use heidy sql, reading the docs i use phpmyadmin directly in my container, but it is all the project so slow

Well, if you want to connect to mysql in container your container has to expose port 3306 by adding something like - 3306:3306 in ports property of mysql service in docker-compose.yml. See ports property in backend or frontend services. But there is better way to import existing data. Mysql container will import any sql file that is in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory. So all you need to do is map the folder with db dump to that directory using something like - /path/to/folder/with/dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated in volumes property.

tnx, this solution works perfectly
